# How to get the src value of a dynamic generated iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i have a function which creates an iframe with content on my page (i have no control on this function because it is also pulled remotely).
the function generates:
     `<span id="myspan"></span>`

once the js function is fully loaded it's:
     `<iframe id="myspan" src="https://google.de">`

my question is, how can i get the src of the iframe.
all tries with .src , getElementById failed or gives my "undefined" as src value. for a normal set iframe the .src etc. works fine. also onload fails on this src.
any ideas ?

i tried 
`<script>var iframeSrc = document.getElementById('#myspan').src;alert(iframeSrc);</script>`
results in undefined.

Comment: Without seeing your code and without seeing any errors, it's impossible to know what your issue is. please update your question with a code snippet that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: That's probably because the iframe does not exist yet when your code is running. You have 2 options here: 1) Wait a few seconds before running your code or 2) Poll for the existence of the iframe in a regular interval.

Comment: can u give me an example code for option 2 ? thanks

Comment: Does the browser allow access to the IFrame Source, not set by the same origin as the requesting script? I doubt it.

Comment: The browser won't allow access to the contents of a third-party iframe, but will allow access to the attributes on the iframe tag itself (because that's still in the parent window.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove the hashtag from your document.getElementById(#id)

Change it to this

```
var iframeSrc = document.getElementById('myspan').src;
alert(iframeSrc);
```

Since you're already stating its an ID in getElementById you don't need to add the hashtag into it.

**Another reason** that your script isn't working is that you might be trying to pull the src before the iframe has been appended to the dom.

If you wanted to check the dom and wait to run some script when the iframe has been appended you could do something like so:

```
var selector = document.getElementById('myspan');
var time = 400;

function waitForElementToDisplay(selector, time) {
        if(document.querySelector(selector)!=null) {
            alert("The element is displayed, you can put your code instead of this alert.")
            return;
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                waitForElementToDisplay(selector, time);
             }, time);
         }
```

Be sure to edit the parameters: selector and time so its matches your code.

Comment: Happy to help - make sure you hit the green tick to whichever answer was the most useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setInterval`, which will run the code specified as a first argument in an interval specified as the second argument. In this case it polls to see if the iframe exists every 500ms.

When the iframe was found, be sure to clear the interval using `clearInterval`, as we don't need to poll anymore.

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() { 
    var iframe = document.getElementById('myspan');

    if (iframe) { 
        clearInterval(intervalId);

        var iframeSrc = iframe.src;
        alert(iframeSrc);
    }
}), 500);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

poll worked, 
    `<script>var existCondition = setInterval(function() {
     if (jQuery("iframe#myspan").length) {
    clearInterval(existCondition);
    var iframeSrc = jQuery("#myspan").attr("src");window.location.replace(iframeSrc)
     }
     }, 100);</script>`